# Hide WPF DataGrid Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to `WPF`. I was having bit different requirement with `DataGrid` so i transform it as below but i dont want any of the scrollbar but its not getting hidden. I have used `LayoutTransform` here row becomes column and column becomes row.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="fuelDataGrid" Width="200" Height="900" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Pump}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          HeadersVisibility="None"  
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
          CanUserResizeRows="False" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False" 
          Cursor="Hand" SelectionMode="Single" 
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="dataGrid2_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" 
          TargetUpdated="DataGrid_OnTargetUpdated">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
           Color="#FFCBCBCB"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="65"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>-->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

    <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>-->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Old Price" Binding="{Binding Row1Value}" /> -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Old Price">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                 // Code here
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Current Price">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                // Code here
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I tried below with Hidden as well. But nothing is working.

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

Answer (score 5):

This simple test case gives me a data grid with no scrollbars:

```
<DataGrid
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

It is bound to a collection of 50 strings. The first few are visible and the rest go out of bounds of the window. No scrollbars appear. Maybe try simplifying your test case until you find the issue?

EDIT: I tried copying your entire data grid xaml and still could not reproduce the issue. Of course, I had to remove the parts that call into unknown code-behind methods, and I substituted a `TextBlock` in the data templates where you typed "// Code here". So, either there is something different about our environments, or the code that is causing the issue is not included in your question.

*Please include the simplest test case that reproduces the issue you are seeing so that someone can actually help you solve it.*

Comment: ya, that you can say its simple. But here i have used `LayoutTransform` my row become column and column become row.

Comment: Adding the layout transforms did not cause scrollbars to appear for me. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this without a scroll view and while showing the complete DataGrid.
You can set height property of datagrid. It would disable or hide the vertical scroll bar. You will set this property on the code behind. By setting the width property, the horizontal scroll bar would be disabled.

You will write this code like this in the constructor.

```
public Mainwindow(){
    datagrid.Height=Double.NaN;
    datagrid.Width=Double.NaN;
}
```